# C - fwrite() not writing first chuck of data from network buffer

Tags: c, sockets, networking, buffer

I'm trying to practice my C programming by making a program that essentially does the 'cp' command to a dedicated server on my home network.

The communication seems to be fine but for some reason the first 8kb of data sent over the wire is not getting written to the file using fwrite... but the PNG header is partially being sent.

**Client.c**

```
uint32_t buffersize = BUFFERSIZE_M; // 8192
size_t file_index;
last_iteration = 0;
char confirmation[BUFFERSIZE_M] = {0};

            if(filelen > buffersize)
            {
                // Read full buffersize
                // subtract buffersize from filesize to determine remainder
                // if remainder is > buffersize -> repeat; else read last segment of file.
                // fileindex is used to guide the filepointer to where the buffer endpoint was/is.

                fread(buffer, 1, buffersize, file);
                file_index = buffersize;

                fseek(file, 0, file_index);
                #ifdef DEBUG
                    printf("filesize: %ld\t\tbuffersize: %d\n", filelen, buffersize);
                #endif
                // Send buffer full of file contents
                getchar(); // Only here so I can visually step through sends

                send(sock, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
                
                filelen = filelen - buffersize;
                file_index = file_index + buffersize;

                // Read socket for confirmation to continue
                // read(sock, confirmation, BUFFERSIZE_S);
                recv(sock, confirmation, BUFFERSIZE_S, 0);

                if(strncmp(confirmation, filename, strlen(filename)) == 0)
                    continue;
                else
                {
                    free(buffer);
                    close(sock);
                    fclose(file);
                    return -1;
                }
            }
```

**Server.c**

```
                while(done == FALSE)
                {
                    // if((s_read = read(s_socket, f_buffer, BUFFERSIZE_XL)) != 0)
                    if((s_read = read(s_socket, f_buffer, BUFFERSIZE_M)) != 0)
                    {
                        if(strncmp(f_buffer, "DONE", strlen("DONE")) == 0)
                        {
                            done = TRUE; 
                        }    
                        else
                        {
                            printf("strlen(buffer): %ld\ts_read: %ld\n", strlen(f_buffer), s_read);
                            fwrite(f_buffer, s_read, 1, output_file);
                            send(s_socket, filename, strlen(filename), 0);
                        }    
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        send(s_socket, filename, strlen(filename), 0); 
                    } 

                    memset(f_buffer, 0, s_read);   
                }
```

**Hexdump of correct PNG**

```
0000000 5089 474e 0a0d 0a1a 0000 0d00 4849 5244
0000010 0000 6c05 0000 8303 0608 0000 2800 48cb
* Normal file contents until 0x2000 *
0002000 **75cc 65f8 6678** 00e9 e732 adf2 e47d 83ee
```

**Hexdump of missing 8kb chunk**

```
0000000 5089 474e 0a0d 0a1a **75cc 65f8 6678** 0ae9
0000010 de20 8651 eaca 14e3 f7d4 e816 a67f f41f
```

Then the rest of the broken PNG file is missing pieces as you can see from the *0ae9* in the broken PNG where it's supposed to be *00e9*.

Can anyone point me in the direction of some C network buffering resources? I cannot seem to find anything on Youtube other than people discussing how to just create sockets.

Comment: Add error checking everywhere.

Comment: If you use TCP socket, there is no need to implement anything for flow control and buffer control. The only thing to implement at the application level is to check for errors everywhere because - by construction - TCP is a reliable protocol. If data can't be transmitted correctly (no error, no duplicate, correct order, everything) it is guaranteed to get an error.

Comment: @fpiette I tried and everything seemed fine. The server gets all the way to the fwrite function and even returns the exact same bytes read, in that s_read variable, that the client sends.

When I tried not using confirmation messages from the server I would successfully send all the data but the server would only write about 1/4 of the amount sent.

Comment: Don't use `strlen()` when sending binary data. It won't send anything after a null byte in the buffer.

Comment: The problem is here: `send(sock, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);`

Comment: @Barmar That was exactly the problem! I really appreciate it... been scratching my head over this for a while.

Comment: @robertstrickland I really advice you to test for error code everywhere. When debugging, looking at the return code for `send()` for example would would immediately point you the error @Barmar told you in his comment above.

Answer (score 0):

From @Barmar in the comments:

> The problem is here: send(sock, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);

That solved the issue and everything is working perfectly now.

Comment: 'everything is working perfectly now'....you may think that:(